# Python - Access to all attributes in a dictionnary

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I would like to access to attribute of objects in a dictionary in order to find the object with the maximum value on this argument.
For example i have this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self,name,value):
        self.name=name
        self.value=value


Dict=dict()

object_1 = MyClass("object_1",1)
Dict[object_1.name]=object_1

object_2 = MyClass("object_2",5)
Dict[object_2.name]=object_2
```

and i would like to do something like:

```
max(dict.value)
```

But i can't figure how to acces the attribute of all the object.
Can you help me please?

Comment: I already tried it, i got a TypeError because max() doesn't work on instances of "Myclass".
I have to find a way to access the attribute of a value of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple genereator fed to max function

```
max(obj.value for obj in Dict.values())
```

Comment: Thanks you very much !

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the max value:

```
maxval = max(x.value for x in Dict.values())
```

If you want the key (name) of this object:

```
name = max(Dict.keys(), key=lambda x: Dict[x.value)
```